# calculating IV and WOE value from weighted GBI

Tags: r

I want to ask a question on how to calculate WOE and IV from weighted GBI in R.

I found the woe package in R, but it only calculate WOE and IV from non weighted GBI and it seems the GBI must be on 0 and 1 only.

Does anyone knows how to manipulate the good bad indicator in this woe package or got information of WOE and IV calculation package with weighted GBI?

Thank you in advance.

Best Regards,
Melody

Comment: Whoa, acronym city! This doesn't really sound like a specific programming question. Possibly one for http://datascience.stackexchange.com or http://stats.stackexchange.com